# Running Ruby scripts in Atom or command shell

Tags: ruby, terminal, console, atom-editor

complete Ruby amateur here. After playing around with Ruby on various interactive online coding environments, I thought I'd try to set up Ruby on my Windows in the same way I've set up Python (using Atom and Terminal-Plus). After being frustrated and Googling for answers the past 3 hours, I thought I'd bring my question here.

Using Python, I can save a file (test.py) in Atom, and execute it using Terminal-Plus by typing:

```
py -i test.py
```

And this would create an interactive shell where I can call any functions I've stored inside my test Python script. I've learnt that I can do a similar thing with Ruby (for a test file test.rb) using:

```
ruby -r test.rb
```

but this yields the following error:

```
C:/Ruby21-  x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such
 file -- test.rb (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

The same thing happens if I use cmd prompt to try and execute the script. I've seen other problems like this where the person was missing a key RubyGem that they were trying to call, but my test.rb file is literally:

```
def xyz
  for i in 1..100
      puts i
  end
end
```

I'm just trying to call a Ruby script and be able to call the functions I've stored in the script in the console, in this case xyz.

Answer (score 0):

`-r` command line switch is used to [use *require* to load *lib* as a library before executing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_command_line_options.htm).

Try

```
ruby test.rb
```

from inside the directory this file is located, it should work.

Comment: Using ruby test.rb seems to compile the code but does not leave my Terminal in a state that I can interact with the code or call upon the function that I've defined. For example, when I type ruby test.rb, my environment does not change into the interactive ruby environment.

Comment: To run a shell with preloaded ruby code, use `irb -r test.rb`.